# jQuery/JavaScript trim HTML that contains white space/empty line

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have the HTML code as below

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
                    <td><img src="/images/pho_01.jpg" width="600" height="63" border="none" style="border: 0px;" alt="photo" /></td>

                    <td></td>


        <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The HTML code is not readable, I want to convert to something likes

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
<td><img src="/images/pho_01.jpg" width="600" height="63" border="none" style="border: 0px;" alt="photo" /></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have ever used the [**$.trim()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), but not works, could someone please suggest a way to 
1. remove space(but don't remove the space between attribute likes `table width="600"`...)
2. remove empty line

Thanks

Comment: Easy way to do it is open the html file in a text editor like gedit or notepad++ and hold down `shift+tab` to indent backwards. If you need a script, I would search for tags and remove the spaces before it on the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your html is stored in a javascript string, you'll have to split it up into multiple lines and use trim on each line.

e.g.

```
function multilineTrim(htmlString) {
   // split the string into an array by line separator
   // call $.trim on each line
   // filter out the empty lines
   // join the array of lines back into a string
   return htmlString.split("\n").map($.trim).filter(function(line) { return line != "" }).join("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try http://jsbeautifier.org/
It works with HTML too

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php